# Gephi: Import Mixed (Directed and Undirected Type in same graph) Network -- How?

Tags: r, gephi

I have a graph where some edges are directed and some are undirected, but I cannot get Gephi to acknowledge both edge types in the same graph.

I am currently using R to manipulate the graph, and then using the 'rgexf' package to encode the graph into a Gephi-readable .gexf file as follows:

```
write.gexf(nodes = nodes_df, edges = edges_df, edgesWeight = E(gD)$weight,
  nodesAtt = nodes_att, edgesAtt = edges_att, nodesVizAtt = nodes_att_viz, 
  edgesVizAtt = edges_att_viz,output = "plag_c_d3.gexf")
```

Here, edgesAtt contains a Type column of strings ('Directed' and 'Undirected'). edgesAtt looks like:

```
Type        weight sourcedate targetdate repost_date_diff
   Directed    100 1361424992 1361426157        0.0134838
 Undirected    100 1362140722 1362140722        0.0000000
   Directed     54 1365403984 1365465600        0.7131481
```

However, when I open Gephi and open the gexf file, Gephi does not read this 'Type' column as the edge type. Instead, it just treats the 'Type' column like any other arbitrary edge attribute, and it adds a new column called 'Type' filled with the default edge type I choose when opening the dataset. Selecting 'mixed' when I import the data does not change this. Gephi does successfully read the 'weight' column as edge weights, however.

How do I make Gephi see both edge types?

**Edit** changing the defaultedgetype attribute to 'mixed' or to 'mutual' also does not work, nor does making each undirected edge into two directional edges that face opposite ways.

Comment: `write.gexf`has a parameter `defaultedgetype`. What if you try to set `defaultedgetype='mixed'`?

Comment: I tried setting defaultedgetype='mixed' and also defaultedgetype='mutual'. When I import the resulting file to Gephi, I get `error: "Default edge type 'mixed' is not recognized. Set to default 'mixed'.` When I try defaultedgetype='mutual' I get `error: "Default edge type "double" is not recognized. Set to default "mixed".` In both cases, Gephi does not recognize my edgesAtt 'Type' column and creates a new one. I also tried switching undirected edges to bi-directional edges in the graph. Gephi then gives an error that "Parallel edges are not yet supported".

Comment: Well I looked at the gexf produced by Gephi for a graph with mixed edges. Take a look at the result: http://pastebin.com/PuaTaKFn. The thing is that the type is not supposed to be an edge attribute *but* an attribute of the XML element `edge`. I hope you understand the difference. Thus, either there should be an option to define the type of the edge in the dataframe where you define the edges and then Gephi will detect the graph type automatically, or there is a bug in `rgexf`

Comment: This is helpful. However, when I try to add a 'Type' column to the `edges` data frame, I get error: `Error in write.gexf(.....:  -edges- should have two columns not 3`. Also, I notice that even though `weight` is an `edgesAtt`, it also shows up as an XML element of edge like so:  
`</edge>
      <edge id="1289" source="399" target="685" weight="93">
        <attvalues>
          <attvalue for="att2" value="93"/>
        </attvalues>
        <viz:color r="255" g="132" b="56" a="0.6"/>
`So rgexf reconizes that 'weight' but not 'type' needs to be added to `edge`. Maybe just an oversight in rgexf?

Comment: OK, I have a workaround... I just wrote a quick Python script that reads the gexf file and edits every edges line to include the type from the edgesAtt line underneath it. Gephi recognizes it, so all is well. Thank you Yannis P. for pointing out the gexf file structure! I assume the reason rgexf was not doing this automatically is just an oversight in the rgexf package code -- not a Gephi problem -- although it would have been nice if Gephi recognized 'type' in edgesAtt as the edge type...

Comment: Nice that you found a solution! To be honest I always do things like that with Python not that is anything wrong with R. Perhaps `networkx` has support for mixed edges but I haven't tried it. I suggest though that you open an issue in rgexf's issue queue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Yannis P.'s notes on how .gexf files store 'type' in mixed types, I built a quick Python 3 script that solves the problem. The script is below. It assumes you have a .gexf file, and that you've stored 'type' in an edgesAtt column named 'type' that contains strings 'Directed' and 'Undirected'. The script reads these and writes them in to the correct place in 'edges' so that Gephi will recognize them. When you open the new script-generated .gexf file in Gephi, just set the type to 'mixed' when importing.

**note**: it's a quick script that eschews error handling and any testing of what it's operating on...use at your own risk and/or add your own catches...but if you're stuck on this as I was, then this should get you started.

```
#Call script like:
#   python this_script.py foo.gexf
#Assumes that in foo.gexf, Type ('Directed' or 'Undirected') is stored as a string column in edgesAtt
#Script outputs a file foo_mixed.gexf that is identical except that mixed Directed and Undirected edge types will be specified in edge elements so that Gephi can read them


import sys
import argparse

def work (args):
    linecount = 0 
    notinnodes = False # nodes att comes first in gexf file

    # Read the whole .gexf input file into memory as a list
    with open (args.fname, 'r') as infile:
        gexf = infile.readlines() 
    infile.close()

    # Create output gexf file
    outfname = args.fname.split('.')[0]+'_mixed'+'.'+args.fname.split('.')[1]
    with open (outfname, 'w') as outgexf:

        for line in gexf:
            # First, ignore the node attributes that come before edge atts in .gexf files
            if '<attributes class=\"edge\"' in line:
                notinnodes = True

            # Get the edge attribute number that contains 'Type' or 'type'
            if notinnodes and 'title=\"type\"' in line.lower():
                Type_attnumber = int(line.split('id=\"att')[1].split('\"')[0])
                break

        # Edit every line that contains an edge element and add the 'type' to it from the attributes listed below it
        for line in gexf:
            if not '<edge id=' in line:
                outgexf.writelines(line)
            else:
                edgeLine = line.split('\"')
                Type = gexf[linecount + 1 + Type_attnumber].split('value=')[1].split('/')[0]
                outgexf.writelines( '\"'.join(edgeLine[0:6])+'\" '+'type='+Type +'\"'.join(edgeLine[6:]) )

            linecount = linecount+1

def main():
    # Parser to grab name of file we're currently working on
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("fname")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    work(args)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```